# indexing matrix multiplication for matlab coder into C

Tags: c, matlab, matrix, matlab-coder

I would like to speed up my euler/Ornstein–Uhlenbeck code, to try to speed up the for loop, using the matlab coder to translate it to C. However, there seems to be a problem with the indexing, but I can not see what is the problem. Thanks a lot..

```
function  [x,t]       = Quick_Euler(N_t,N,A,G,dt) 
   x      = zeros(N,N_t);
   t      = zeros(1,N_t); 
for i = 2 : N_t
   n         = randn([N,1]);   
   x(1:N,i)  = x(1:N,i-1)     + dt^(.5)*G*n + (A*x(1:N,i))*dt;
   t(1,i)    = t(1,i-1)   + dt;      
end  
end
```

Compiler:

```
>&gt; coder -build Quick_Euler.prj
??? Size mismatch (size [:? x 1] ~= size [:? x :?]).
<br>Mismatched varying and fixed sizes indicate a probable run-time error.
If this diagnostic is incorrect, use indexing to explicitly make the varying size fixed.
```

Comment: What dimension are your input arguments?

Comment: My experience (with an older Matlab relase) is that using the Coder won't speed up your calculations (in many cases it even slows that down). If you want to gain speed, either vectorize your code as much as you can, or write that in C/Fortran and use as a mex function.

Comment: Hi Daniel,  my input arguments are : A and G are matrices of N*N, the others are doubles...